# How can i bind from one function to another in python

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

Im trying to make my code bind to red only at first
and make red's handler rebind to yellow after red finishes. Im not sure how to do this. Would anyone know how this is done. Because in my code if you run it. It only runs the yellow function instead of red and im pretty sure this is because im overwriting the bind function.

```
from tkinter import *
import random
root = Tk()
root.geometry("300x300")
score = 0
lb1 = Listbox(root)
e = Entry(root)



def binder1():
    root.bind('<Return>', red)


def red(event):
    print(e.get())
    if e.get() == "red":
        lb1.insert("end", "Correct")
        binder1
        global score
        score += 1
        mb4['text'] = str("Score ") + str(score)


redcolour = Label(root, text = "What colour is this boi!", fg = "Red")


def yellow(event):
    print(e.get())
    if e.get() == "yellow":
        lb1.insert("end", "Correct")
        global score
        score += 1
        mb4['text'] = str("Score ") + str(score)

root.bind('<Return>', yellow)
yellowcolour = Label(root, text = "What colour is this boi!", fg = "Yellow")


mb4= Menubutton(root, text = str("Score: ") + str(score))
mb4.menu = Menu(mb4)





e.focus_set()
e.pack()
yellowcolour.pack()
redcolour.pack()
lb1.pack()
mb4.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear for me why you want to bind red first.

I would make it more dynamically and let make decision by user input.

like this:

```
from tkinter import *

def check_input(event):
    global score
    my_input = e.get()
    if my_input == "yellow":
        lb1.insert("end", "Correct yellow")
        score += 1
        mb4['text'] = str("Score ") + str(score)
    elif my_input == "red":
        lb1.insert("end", "Correct red")
        score += 1
        mb4['text'] = str("Score ") + str(score)
    else:
        return None


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("300x300")
    root.bind('<Return>', check_input)
    score = 0

    lb1 = Listbox(root)
    e = Entry(root)
    redcolour = Label(root, text = "What colour is this boi!", fg = "Red")  
    yellowcolour = Label(root, text = "What colour is this boi!", fg = "Yellow")
    mb4= Menubutton(root, text = str("Score: ") + str(score))

    e.focus_set()

    e.pack()
    yellowcolour.pack()
    redcolour.pack()
    lb1.pack()
    mb4.pack()

    root.mainloop()
```